# How to develop a package I also have installed?

Tags: git, package-development

When developing a package which is also installed via an online repository, there is a practical problem.

- `/source/my-emacs-package`

  git repository where I have my code.
- `~/.config/emacs/elpa/my-emacs-package-20200127.1052`

  The location the package is installed.

Currently I'm manually removing & symlinking files between these directories, however this is quite cumbersome since you need to remember to remove the `*.elc` files and the path name changes after each update.

---

How should I switch to my local git repository temporarily while developing my package?

Using a single switch for example, at the beginning of my `init.el`.

```el
;; Set to t to load local packages.
(defconst use-my-local-packages nil)
```

Comment: I would use a second emacs instance tailored to load (and reload) the development version. If something goes wrong, you kill the second instance, restart it and you are back in business. If you use your primary emacs for testing the development version, you'd be toast in such a scenario.

Comment: I turn off `.el` and `.elc` files by just changing the names, e.g., `foo.el.off` and `foo.elc.off`.  If you have lots of them, then `wdired`/`grep` and `multiple-cursors` can do them all in one fell swoop.  When your done developing or when you break Emacs so bad its unusable, disable the developmental and re-enable the tried/true working version.  The tried/true versions can shadow/supersede the path to the developmental versions, but when the tried/true is off, the developmental is first in time.  The entire directory on the `load-path` can be turned off/on; or change the `load-path` ...

Comment: Changing names whenever you want to develop a package isn't practical since it's too easy to forget to rename back (if you have many packages).

Comment: Uninstall the package or shadow the installed package via `load-path`, for example, with `(use-package foo :ensure t :load-path "~/src/foo")`, Emacs will prefer ~/src/foo.

Comment: Is it possible to optionally pass in `:load-path "~/src/foo"` ? otherwise I need to edit `use-package` use every time.

Comment: AFAIK the [straight](https://github.com/raxod502/straight.el#features) package manager is especially designed for that purpose. Switching from the development version to the stable version is essentially a git-checkout. I do not use it (yet) and I do not know how byte-compilation is handled. But, I would initially skip byte-compilation for the few packages that I am maintaining. Testing with the byte compiled library is then a pre-release step.

Comment: Instead of symlinking individual files, could you just symlink the directory? i.e., `ln -s my-dev-package/ path/to/elpa/package`. You could move the directory from the elpa version somewhere else, and then point the link to it when that's the version you want to use. That would only require one change to switch between the released and development versions. As long as you don't update the package from elpa...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since asking this question I've found `use-package` & `straight` can be used for this purpose.

Given this `use-package` example.

```el
(use-package recomplete
  :commands (recomplete-ispell-word))
```

Can be made to use the local path:

```el
(use-package recomplete
  :commands (recomplete-ispell-word)

  ;; This causes my local copy to be used.
  :straight
  (recomplete
    :type git
    :host gitlab
    :local-repo "/my/local/path/to/emacs-recomplete"
    :repo "ideasman42/emacs-recomplete"))
```

Answer (score 0):

consider passing in a command line argument that alters the load-path perhaps? eg here I have a "-chat" switch.

```
(add-to-list 'command-switch-alist '("chat" . rgr/load-chats))
(defun rgr/load-chats(switch) 
  (require  'rgr-chat))
```

Modify this to modify the load-path right at the start of your init.el or whatever your startup is.

Comment: I won't delete my answer yet, but now I think about it you'd need to ensure these are processed prior to the loading of your package of course